# sessions values unchangeable after submit

Tags: forms, session, updates

I have a form with multiple submit,so, I have to keep input data from the form,I used SESSION for storing data.On my form I have to handle some actions,and at the end (the last submit) I have to unset all SESSIONS,My problem is when I didn't reach the last submit,the values of input data from the form can't be changed.(Values remain the same even if I change them--Because I stored them in SESSION),Is there a way to update the session variable before I submit for the last time?

Here is a part of my code :

```
  if (isset($_POST["name"])){
      $_SESSION["name"]    = $_POST["name"];
      $_SESSION["surname"]   = $_POST["surname"];
  }  
    echo"<form name='form' action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<input name=\"name\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $_SESSION["name"]. "\">";
    echo "<input name=\"surname\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $_SESSION["surname"]. "\">";
    echo"<input type='submit' name='add_user' value="ADD">";
    echo"<input type='submit' name='organize' value="ORDER">";
    echo"<input type='submit' name='submit' value="SEND">";
    echo"</form>"
```

Comment: Sessions are on the server, you can't do anything with them BEFORE the submit.

Comment: Of course I use them with my form which has multiple submit,for the first submit I keep values of my POST values

Comment: But you can't do anything before the last submit because you can't do anything before _any_ submit. PHP doesn't run until after the submit.

Comment: Maybe you just need a timeout on your sessions?

Comment: So,my $_SESSION["name"] and $_SESSION["username"] values will stay unchangeable until the last submit?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well my question,...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Every time the user submits the form, your script sets the session variables to whatever is currently in the form.